# Entity class is a JavaBean?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, entity, javabeans

I am newbie for learning Java EE and still many concepts confuse me. I found an entity class looks like a JavaBean.

1. Is an entity class a JavaBean? (please explain something here)
2. What is the relationship between an entity class and JPA? (my understanding: is JPA a tech/API used with an entity class, which persists the data from a database?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `@Entity` is not a JavaBean (the JavaBean convention requires a public no-arg constructor, `@Entity` can have protected etc.) but they are very similar. `@Entity` is actually a POJO (Plain Old Java Object). You can compare conventions and requirements for JavaBeans and Entity classes:

1. [JavaBeans conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions)
2. [Requirements for Entity classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqb)

A class annotated with `@Entity` will usually represent a table in a relational database. You can use them through JPA to perform insert/update/.. operations on a database. An example:

```
UserTransaction utx;
EntityManager em;
//initialization of entity manager..
utx.begin();
 YourEntity entity = new YourEntity(); //your @Entity annotated class
 entity.setSomeParam(someValue);
 em.persist(entity);
utx.commit();
```

See also:

- [The Java EE 6 Tutorial (entities)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html)
- [Java persistence API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html)

Comment: 1. Does mean that the only difference between JavaBeans and Entity Class  is the "constructor"?                                                    2. JPA is used in entity class for persisting the data/interacting with DB?

Comment: @KurtX I've updated my answer. JPA is an API, i.e. it provides a set of interfaces to deal with DB. Entity class is a main unit of interaction, it is a base of object-relational mapping. That means - changing the properties of Entity class and invoking `merge`,`persist` and other methods will result with changes in your database.